# SwiftUI VStack - make the background fill the entire screen in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The background doesn't fill the entire screen in landscape. How can I make it stretch all the way?

[image: White margins on the horizontal sides of the black background]

Here's my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            VStack {
                Text("Instant Developer")
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Get help from expert in 15 minutes")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 20) {
                Image("student")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                Image("tutor")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
            
            Text("Need help with coding problem? Register!")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            Spacer()
            
            if verticalSizeClass == .compact {
                HSignUpButtonGroup()
            } else {
                VSignUpButtonGroup()
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 30)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be because of `scaledToFit`, which tries to preserve the image's aspect ratio and so doesn't make the background extend all the way.

To fix, just make the background stretch as much as it can with [`.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/frame(minwidth:idealwidth:maxwidth:minheight:idealheight:maxheight:alignment:)). Make sure to put this modifier before `background` so that the color respects the new layout.

```
.padding(.top, 30)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity) /// here!
.background(Color.black)
```

Comment: I got it, Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Loyio np. Also if it worked, can you click the green checkmark to accept the answer? Helps other people find answers easier.